# Ubuntu Roll Up Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, wireless-keyboards

This is about the Roll Up Keyboard found at shop.ubuntu.com

Does anybody know if it's wireless?  I have a Cubox-i and I would like to know if I can just roll the keyboard in my backpack when I go to a hotel with my Cubox-i and use it wirelessly.  If it is wired that's fine, but I would rather not have to use this long cord.

Comment: Oh, and I can't add the keyboard to the cart.  Do I have to get a Chinese Layout?  Will that still be in English lettering?

Comment: Do you mean [this one](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=800)? - it would help to give a link to the product.

Comment: @Wilf that is the only one I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is [this one](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=800).

Looking at the image, it does have a wire:

[image: Image of wired flexible keyboard]

It also says in the description that it has:

> USB and PS2 interface

And that it operates at:

> 5V DC

Which is the voltage for a USB, and I don't know of a combo of batteries that gives 5V.

And no, Chinese layout won't be English lettering as far as I know. I guess it is currently out of stock.

[Try this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/PK-Green-Flexible-Foldable-Silicone/dp/B000UMJFJU)?

Comment: Also, the contact form on the canonical webstore is probably where the OP should have asked the question. I feel its not really appropriate for this site. Could just be me, though. http://shop.canonical.com/contact_us.php